# Accessing Web Services from iPhone on PC through network

Tags: iphone, iis, web-services, networking

I asked a very similar question not too long ago and got some great responses. I've made it pretty far but still can't quite get things to talk. What I have is a PC running IIS and a web service inside of that. I'm trying to get the iPhone simulator on my Mac to be able to see this web service. I can ping my PCs local IP address from the Mac just fine, it's clearly alive and on the network. However, no matter what URL I enter into Safari the web service will not appear.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a web service or web application?

One fair possibility is that your Windows firewall could be blocking access to port 80. If it is, open your Windows firewall settings and add an exception for port 80 (Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Exceptions).

You might try using telnet on your Mac to test connecting to the web service/application.

Comment: It's a web service, does that change things?

Comment: Also, I can access the URL http://localhost/GCWEB/service1.asmx from my PC just fine. Through the Mac is a different problem however...

Comment: Got it :-) Just needed to use the IP address of the PC in the URL. For me, that was http://192.168.1.147/GCWEB/service1.asmx

Comment: Either way, it could be a blocked port.